# Azure Devops API, How can I tell if an agent is running a build?

Tags: rest, azure-devops

This api
`https://me.visualstudio.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools/12/agents/123`
give me information like "enabled": true, and "status": "online", but does not indicate if this machine is running a build or Idle.

I can see that info on page 
`https://me.visualstudio.com/_settings/agentpools?poolId=102&view=agents` under Current Status. Is there an API that gives me Current Status?

Comment: Very agree with MarcD's solution, to display more info about the agent, you need expand some parameters in your API. Then you will see the detailed message which about its build running, if this agent is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the querystring `includeAssignedRequest=true` to get any jobs currently assigned the specific agent. If the agent is currently running a job, the response contains an `assignedRequest` object

`https://me.visualstudio.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools/12/agents/123?includeAssignedRequest=true`

See [includeAssignedRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)