# Get CurrentStatus of AzureDevOps-Agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to find out the "Current Status" of an agent (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgent) via the AzureDevOps WebApi?
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgRCh.png)

Unfortunately, so far I have only found the option to set the status and not to read it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.webapi.taskagenthttpclientbase.updateagentupdatestateasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet

I would be grateful for any information.
Best regards Paddy

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570531/azure-devops-api-how-can-i-tell-if-an-agent-is-running-a-build.

Comment: Yes. We can add the includeAssignedRequest  to true when using the this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.webapi.taskagenthttpclientbase.getagentasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgent. Then we can check the AssignedRequest  in the response to determine if it is in idle state. You can check if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out the "Current Status" of an agent

Yes. You can use the method: [TaskAgentHttpClientBase.GetAgentsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.webapi.taskagenthttpclientbase.getagentasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) and set the **includeAssignedRequest** to true.

To determine if the agent is Idel or busy, you can check the [AssignedRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.webapi.taskagent?view=azure-devops-dotnet) value in the response.

If the AssignedRequest value is null or empty, this means that the agent is in Idle State.

If the AssignedRequest returns the content, this means that the agent is running the related builds.